# Loading DLLs built for different runtime versions in .NET Core AssemblyLoadContext

Tags: .net-core, coreclr, assembly-loading

We use .NET 6's `AssemblyLoadContext` to setup a plugin system.

Is it, for example, possible to load a .NET Core 3 or a .NET 5 dll in an `AssemblyLoadContext` in a process that was built for .NET 6? And what are the implications and/or side-effects of doing so?

Are there certain best practices that should be taken into consideration, or is mixing runtime versions in `AssemblyLoadContext`s something that shouldn't be done at all?